# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$balance

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.8

I have a Many to Many relationship between `Wallet` & `User` Models:

**User.php**:

```
public function wallets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');
    }
```

**Wallet.php**:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id')->withPivot('balance');
    }
```

And the pivot table `user_wallet` goes like this:

[image]

Now I need to get the name of wallets and the balance of that wallet in a table at Blade.

So at the Controller, I added this:

```
public function index($id)
{
   // $id is the user id
   $userWallet = Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users',function ($query)use($id){
      $query->where('user_id',$id);
   })->get();
}
```

And then at the Blade:

```
@forelse($userWallet as $wallet)
   <div class="message_fullName">
   {{ $wallet->name }}
   </div>

   <div class="message_tag">
   {{ $wallet->users()->balance }}
   </div>
@empty
   Empty
@endforelse
```

But I get this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$balance
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly get the `balance` at the pivot table?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop user

```
@forelse($userWallet as $wallet)
   <div class="message_fullName">
   {{ $wallet->name }}
   </div>

   <div class="message_tag">
    @if(isset($wallet->users)&&count((array)$wallet->users))
      @foreach($wallet->users as $user)
        {{$user->pivot->balance }}
      @endforeach
    @endif
   </div>
@empty
   Empty
@endforelse
```

Your query should be

```
$userWallet = Wallet::with(["users"=>function ($query)use($id){
      $query->where('user_id',$id);
   }])->whereHas('users',function ($query)use($id){
      $query->where('user_id',$id);
   })->get();
```

Comment: But this will get the balance of all users and not the specified user with `$id` at the Controller

Comment: if its one user  {{ $wallet->users->first()->pivot->balance }} so no need of loop

Comment: You're awesome bro. How can I learn the relationships in Laravel fully like you? Can u give me some tips plz.

Comment: @tejoslaeslio jsut debug line by line and try for existing answers it might not be exact same as you wanted but using that clue try error and trails

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use the relation's query builder object with `users()` but you need `user` property to get the collection:

```
@forelse($userWallet as $wallet)
   <div class="message_fullName">
   {{ $wallet->name }}
   </div>

   <div class="message_tag">
   {{ $wallet->users->balance }}
   </div>
@empty
   Empty
@endforelse
```

But even the collection instance doesn't have a balance property as long as it is not a custom collection. You probably need to loop over the collection or use `pluck` to get the model's `balance` property:

```
@forelse($userWallet as $wallet)
   <div class="message_fullName">
   {{ $wallet->name }}
   </div>

   <div class="message_tag">
   {{ $wallet->users->pluck('balance')->join(', ') }}
   </div>
@empty
   Empty
@endforelse
```

Comment: It's not showing balance! However it exists. It just shows `, `